Android Studio - Build Error but works on another machine
I have an Android app that is failing to build in Android Studio.  The app has been around for several years now, and I've had no issues in the past with building or running it.  A few weeks ago, I upgraded to a newer laptop and installed everything fresh, including Android Studio Kohala 2024.1.2.  Now for some reason, when I try to build the app, it fails and states
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1.

In the build log it shows over and over how it tried to resolve the dependency and failed.
Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-notifications-handler/1.0.1/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-notifications-handler/1.0.1/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/microsoft/azure/azure-notifications-handler/1.0.1/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/microsoft/azure/azure-notifications-handler/1.0.1/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

What is truly strange though is a fellow developer who is running the same version of Android Studio and Windows 11 is able to build it without any issue.  I've gone through and compared settings, build.gradle files, etc., and all match - so I'm 100% stumped.
Here is what I've got in the gradle files.  Does anyone know what I can try to resolve this?
build.gradle (app level)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    namespace 'XXX-MYAPPID-XXX'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX-MYAPPID-XXX"
        minSdkVersion 26
        compileSdk 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 400
        versionName = "4.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.7'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.9.1"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        name "jcenter"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

build.gradle (project level)
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    } }

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.layout.buildDirectory }


Since JCenter shut down on August 15, 2024, the library com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1 that is fetching resources from JCenter.

->  implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:2.0.0' <- try this one.

@JaydeepKhambhayta Thanks for the info.  After seeing your comment, I reached back into a backup I had of my old machine, grabbed the AAR files from the gradle cache directory and loaded them directly in gradle.  Project finally builds again.  Thanks!!
